# Python3 code help unable to display total to user

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem Statement:** My first python code, need help - I'm successful in creating txt file with different entries but unable to get the total displayed when done. Eventually would like to record "total" entry in txt file as well but 1 problem at a time.

REQUIREMENT:

- Create a txt file with input of grocery list
- Ask user for input of Grocery item and then another input for Price of the item
- when user enters quit, display the total of all the entered grocery items

```
f = open("grocery_list.txt", "w")
while True:

    usrkey_input = input("Item Purchased: ")
    if usrkey_input == "quit":
        def sum(usrvalue_input):
            total = 0
            for price in usrvalue_input:
                total = total + price
            return total
        break
    usrvalue_input = input("Price in $: ")
    f.write(usrkey_input + " ," + usrvalue_input + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: You're defining a function `sum` (in the wrong place), but never calling it.  You don't need the function at all.  Before your loop, set `total = 0`. After writing the values to file, you need `total = total + int(usrvalue_input)`, assuming the prices are integers.  Then, after the while loop when you close the file, you print `total`.

Comment: Thank you!! Now Im able to get total after every entry but now have to figure out to only get it when keyword "quit" is entered.

Comment: I told you that.  You `print(total)` AFTER you exit the loop, which means it is at column 0, like the `f.close()` statement.

Comment: Thank you Tim!! I totally misread your initial comment. It works now the way I wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do like -

```
with open("grocery_list.txt", "w") as f:
    total = 0
    usr_value_input_price = []
    while True:
        usr_key_input = input("Item Purchased: ")
        if usr_key_input == "quit":
            total = sum(usr_value_input_price)
            break
        usr_value_input = input("Price in $: ")
        usr_value_input_price.append(int(usr_value_input))
        f.writelines(usr_key_input + " ," + usr_value_input + '\n')
    print('Total price: ', total)
    f.writelines('Total Price ,' + str(total))
```